# Is it possible to perform I/O in constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, constexpr

```
#include <iostream>

class test
{
public:
    constexpr void setX(int val);
private:
    int x;
};

constexpr void test::setX(int val)
{
    x = val;
    std::cout << "x : " << x << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    test obj;
    obj.setX(5);
    return 0;
}
```

Here the question is, I am not able to perform I/O operations for debugging in this constexpr function. So is there any way to do I/O operations inside the constexpr function or is this is a limitation/ behavior in C++?

Comment: No. `constexpr` stuff wants to be computed at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently what you have is ill-formed no diagnostic required as per [C++11 [dcl.constexpr]p5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/dcl.constexpr#5):

> For a constexpr function, if no function argument values exist such
>   that the function invocation substitution would produce a constant
>   expression ([expr.const]), the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic
>   required. For a constexpr constructor, if no argument values exist
>   such that after function invocation substitution, every constructor
>   call and full-expression in the mem-initializers would be a constant
>   expression (including conversions), the program is ill-formed; no
>   diagnostic required. [ Example:
>
> ```
> constexpr int f(bool b)
>   { return b ? throw 0 : 0; }               // OK
> constexpr int f() { throw 0; }              // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
>
> struct B {
>   constexpr B(int x) : i(0) { }             // x is unused
>   int i;
> };
>
> int global;
>
> struct D : B {
>   constexpr D() : B(global) { }             // ill-formed, no diagnostic required
>                                             // lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on non-constant global
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

and if you try to use it in a context that requires a constant expression this will become a hard error e.g.:

```
constexpr test obj;
```

[see godbolt example live](https://godbolt.org/z/L7aLiw).

We can see from [[expr.const]p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.const#2.2) we are restricted to calling `constexpr` functions:

> an invocation of a function other than a constexpr constructor for a literal class or a constexpr function [ Note: Overload resolution ([over.match]) is applied as usual  — end note ];

and `cout` and other I/O functions are not marked `constexpr`.

Quotes for C++14 are similar [[dcl.constexpr]p5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.constexpr#5) and [[expr.const]p2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/expr.const#2.2).

Comment: You're right but for completeness is there other way insted of using the `std::cout`? What about some compilers "debug" warnings (e.g. through pragmas) but i can't think of any proper way how to get into those warnings value of some variable.

Comment: @Qeek Relevant reading: [constexpr-function-parameters](https://mpark.github.io/programming/2017/05/26/constexpr-function-parameters/).  Offhand, I don't see how you would do it if you insist on it being an ordinary function argument and a constexpr.

Comment: OP's example is completely ill-formed C++11 anyway, so I'd proceed on the assumption that they are compiling as C++14. ("function invocation substitution" is unique to C++11 constexpr and isn't something I'd bring up in a C++14-or-later context.)